# Как отправить в метод типа char параметр типа int?

Tags: java, ооп, методы

Всем привет. В общем, надо передать значение типа int (x и y), считываемые с клавиатуры, в метод char, вернув в качестве значения двумерный массив все того же типа char. И вот понятия не имею как это реализовать... Перелазил достаточное количество страничек в интернете, но решения подобной проблемы так и не нашел. Я в Java еще новичок, так что не пинайте сильно за глупый вопрос. Всем, кто сможет наставить на путь истинный, большое спасибо.

```
import java.util.*;

public class GameLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       GameLogic player = new GameLogic();
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       char[][] grid = new char[3][3];
       for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
               grid[i][j] = '·';
               System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " ");
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
       while (true) {
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("Введите номер строки: ");
           int x = sc.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Введите номер строки: ");
           int y = sc.nextInt();
           grid[x][y] = player.setCell(x,y);
       }
   }
}

public class GameLogic {
    public int setCell (int x, int y){
        char[][] cellValue = new char[1][1];
        cellValue[x][y] = 'X';
        return cellValue[x][y];
    }
}
```

Comment: Для этого есть приведение типов: `int a = 3; char b = (char)a;` Только вот в коде непонятно для чего это нужно, там есть проблемы побольше. В `setCell` возвращается двумерный массив как число, к тому же, он единичного размера, а в него кто-то пытается вставлять число не знай куда... Кажется, цель этого метода будет достигнута, если его удалить x) А заместо `player.setCell(x,y);` написать просто 'X'.

Comment: Но если есть цель вынести всю эту механику в объект, тогда уж в нём и создавать сам массив нужно, там же его и обрабатывать. И кстати, не забудьте  предусмотреть выход из цикла.

Comment: Просто я именно что пытаюсь вынести всю логику, которую возможно вынести, в отдельный класс. Потому и не пишу в main-классе все :) Выходит, той цели, которой я добиваюсь, не добиться тем путем, по которому пошел я?

Comment: Добиться, конечно. Сейчас напишу развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Верно, программу нужно разбивать на компоненты, которые должны отвечать за обработку конкретных данных и решение определённых задач. В Вашем случае нужно вынести все части, что напрямую относятся к массиву. То есть, его создание и обработка должны происходить в отдельном классе.

```
public class GameLogic {
    /// константы хорошо бы выносить
    public static final int size = 3;

    /// скрытая от внешнего мира переменная массива
    private char[][] grid;

    /// конструктор класса с инициализацией полей
    public GameLogic () {
        grid = new char[size][size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
               grid[i][j] = '·';
           }
        }
    }

    /// тоже стоит вынести, в будущем может пригодиться
    public void print () {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
               System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " ");
           }
        }
    }

    /// помечает указанную ячейку данным значением
    public void setCell (int x, int y, char val){
        // проверка корректности индексов
        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < size && y < size)
            grid[x][y] = val;
    }
}


public class GameLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // просто создаём
       GameLogic player = new GameLogic();
       // и выводим
       player.print();
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       while (true) {
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println("Введите номер строки: ");
           int x = sc.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Введите номер строки: ");
           int y = sc.nextInt();
           if (x < 0 || y < 0)
               break;
           player.setCell(x, y, 'X');
       }
   }
}
```

Значение в `setValue` может и не надо выносить в аргумент, зависит от Ваших целей.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы очень сильно мне помогли :)